# MVC upload csv file not working in IIS 5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently use the code from the following website:
http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/net-mvc-upload-a-csv-file-to-database-with-bulk-upload/#comment-188

The problem is the Upload would not work in IIS 5.1 (.net framework 4) but work in IIS 7.5 (.net framework 4).

Comment: *Not work* could mean quite a lot of things. Please clarify.

Comment: It is not save the record to the database.

Comment: What happened when you debugged your code by stepping through it? Was there some error message?

Comment: Hi Darin, There is no error in the code. I also put the trace in webconfig and still no error.

Comment: Hi Darin, I have test using VS 2010 framework .4 on XP machine and it work fine. but by the the time deploy to the IIS 5.1 it does not work.

Comment: I use the following code to trigger action in the controller with button click"
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ConsumerDetails", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
           
}

Comment: Try debugging your code by placing breakpoints. Hopefully you will eventually find out the problem.

Comment: Hi Darin, the problem is the folder for upload is denied. I found out by attaching IIS process for the debugging. THank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the folder is not accessible. Thanks for Darin Dimitrov for his helps